# Releasing app without Today extension?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I got a Today extension half done in my project.
I don't have to release a half done product to public but also want to keep the same codebase so I can save time on code maintenance.

Does anyone know a way to release the app without the Today extension built-it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the application target settings,

- Remove the today extension from the "target dependencies" list.
- Remove the today extension from the "embed app extensions" list.

Then clean and build. You'll get a build of the app with no today extension.

When you want to go back to working on the today extension, reverse the two steps above.

Comment: Thanks man, just to be clearer. Open main app target setting -> Build Phases -> Remove widget from Target Dependencies and Embed App Extensions. When you want to add it back, reverse the steps (the embed app sitting in Products folder)